# Symfony2, 2 similiar types of users, best approach

Tags: symfony

i have this project where i have an issue, there are 3 relevant enteties.

```
User:
   has_many: Leads

Bot:
   has_many: Leads

Lead:
   has_one: User/Bot
```

Now, a user and a bot share a lot of the same things, but they use different firewalls, they have many different fields etc, but i want a user and a bot to be interchangeable in regards of who a lead belongs to, it can either belong to a bot or a user, never both at the same time.

And in many of my other enteties where i run stats etc, i refere to a single field, i dont check if there is a user or a bot.

Is it possible to make these 2 enteties share the same Primary key and then just somehow refer to a single entity in the Lead field ?

Or what would be the best design approach in Symfony?

Answer (score 1):

If you have all fields the same in 2 entities I would recommend you to drop Bot entity at all. All you need is just one field `type` with available values `bot` and `user`. To optimize SQL queries I would recommend you to declare this field as ENUM type.

Also if you really need different entities you can use [Single table inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) with discriminator field `type` described above.